# Skipping waiting for OLE action to complete

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am currently trying to run 6 transaction in SAP from a VBA code, but the waiting time is too long, because VBA starts the transactions one after another. I am therefore interested in starting all 6 transactions at the same time, to minimize the waiting time. Is this possible?

Is it possible to go to the next line in the VBA script if the VBA script is waiting for OLE action to complete?

I appreciate all help!

Kasper

Comment: The search term you want is 'asynchronous'. Your SAP library may or may not be asynchronous. If it isn't you're out of luck. You might want to share some code with us and maybe the exact name of the library.

Comment: i don't think so in VBA, as Nick said Asynchronous is the way forward or moving to a .NET version and use threading/tasks.  What is happening in the transactions, taking the time?

Comment: First of all, you must open 6 different SAP GUI sessions so that to execute ABAP code in parallel at SAP side, because you can't have 1 session run different ABAP programs at the same time. If you create 6 different scripts, each opening a session, and you run them manually, that answers your question.